# App crashing due to Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) Pending intent issue even after specifying the FLAG_IMUTABLE

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

The app that is crashing is a legacy application that is still using GCM for notifications without any support but when I upgraded the app to Target sdk api 33, it started crashing in the phones that are on Android api 31 or above and started throwing the following exception:

```
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
 
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depenat android.app.PendingIntent.checkPendingIntent(PendingIntent.java:428)

at android.app.PendingIntent.checkPendingIntent(PendingIntent.java:428)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:731)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:718)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzl.zzi(Unknown Source:18)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzl.zzb(Unknown Source:224)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzl.zza(Unknown Source:0)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzb(Unknown Source:60)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source:120)
```

When I debugged I found out that the app was crashing at the following line:

```
regid = instanceID.getToken(SENDER_ID, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

There is no option for updating GCM to Firebase as this would require a big effort and resources.

Comment: Have you tried `FLAG_MUTABLE` as well? All Pending Intents were previously Mutable.

Comment: @Andrew Already tried that

Answer (score 0):

You must update firebase messaging sdk version to the latest one
current latest version is 23.3.1

Comment: I am using GCM not firebase.

Comment: Please let me know why you are not using firebase?

Comment: it's a legacy app, and this SDK change will preempt more changes more precisely full app will be rebuilt and this can't be done now. Can you help me on this.